# Optimizing nested If statements and conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

Say I have three conditions, represented by Boolean variables. How do I make the following blocks of code simpler?

```
bool condition1, condition2, condition3; //assuming they already have values

if (condition1 && condition2)
{
    if (condition3)
    {
        //Few lines of code here
    }
}
else
{
    //Same few lines of code above here
}
```

Is there a better/neater way of simplifying this, aside from putting the 'lines of code' in a method? Can the inner `if` be removed? Thanks.

Comment: are there any lines in the outer if (that are not in the inner)

Comment: @EpicKip If you're talking about outside the `if (condition3)` check, then no. The `if` there is alone. :)

Comment: Can't you do `if(con1 && con2 && con3)` then `else if(!con1 && !con2)`?

Comment: @EpicKip Will give it a try. Hang on a sec. Thanks.

Comment: If it works ill post it as answer

Comment: @EpicKip that is not necessary. Since both results in the same executed code all equations can be evakluated in the same if statement

Comment: If its the exactly the same yes, but the question is not 100% clear as there is no actual code. if it all were the same the else wouldn't be there. And i'm looking for the solution to OP's problem, if I find the solution I will post it

Comment: If it clears any confusion, the code inside the inner `if` is the same with what's in the outer `else` block. Still testing y'all codes for a minute

Comment: @RomanoZumbé In that case your first if should be fine -> didn't quite see the structure here but see it now

Comment: @AwonDanag Go with Romano's first if -> that does exactly what you want

Comment: Code of @RomanoZumbé worked. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with this:

```
if (!(condition1 && condition2) || (condition1 && condition2 && condition3))
{
     //Few lines of code here
}
```

Or equate `condition1 && condition2` before the `if` statement to make the code simpler:

```
bool c12 = condition1 && condition2;

if (!c12 || (c12 && condition3))
{
     //Few lines of code here
}
```

If you need to do additional things if `condition1` and `condition2` are true (but not condition3):

```
bool c12 = condition1 && condition2;

if (!c12 || (c12 && condition3))
{
     if(c12 && !condition3)
     {
         // Do extra stuff
     }

     //Few lines of code here
}
```

Comment: This worked. Don't know who downvoted, though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the same and smaller code:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3)
{
        //Few lines of code here
}
else
{
    //Same few lines of code above here
}
```

Comment: The original `else` gets hit independent of the value of `condition3`